# Django code organisation

Tags: python, django

I've recently started working with Django.  I'm working on an existing Django/Python based site. In particular I'm implementing some functionality to create and display a PDF document when a particular URL is hit. I have an entry in the app's urls file that routes to a function in the views file and the PDF generation is working fine.

However, the view function is pretty big and I want to extract the code out somewhere to keep my view as thin as possible, but I'm not sure of the best/correct approach.  I'll probably need to generate other PDFs in due course so would it make sense to create a 'pdfs' app and put code in there?  If so, should it go in a model or view?

In a PHP/CodeIgniter environment for example I would put the code into a model, but models seem to be closely linked to database tables in Django and I don't need any db functionality for this.

Any pointers/advice from more experienced Django users would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The model should only be used for the database. The heavy work should be done in the view. It is good practice to create one app for every task. If you only have one task (pdf creation) and your view is still too big, you could simply create a file create_pdf.py and do the heavy work there.

Comment: Thanks, so is it OK to do heavy work in a view? A view in Django acts like a controller in other frameworks and my instinct is to keep business processing out of controllers as much as possible and delegate the work to models

Comment: Yes views are the controllers. I tend to try to insert as much functionality as possible into the models to get around the `Object-relational impedance mismatch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to scale your project, I would suggest moving it to a separate app. Generally speaking, generating PDFs based on an url hit directly is not the best thing to do performance-wise. **Generating a PDF file is pretty heavy on you server, so if multiple people do it at the same time, the performance of your system will suffer.**

As a first step, just put it in a separate class, and execute that code from the view. **At some point you will probably want to do some permission checks etc - that stays in the view, while generation of the PDF itself will be cleanly separated.**

Once you test your code, scale etc - then you can substitute that one line call in the view into putting the PDF generation in a queue and only pulling it once it's done - that will allow you to manage your computing powers better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great advice :-)  I should have clarified - I'm only using the URL in the browser whilst I'm testing.  In production the PDF will only be generated (and then attached to an email) when someone purchases a service via the site, so the functionality will be triggered by a callback from the payment gateway and there won't be a public facing URL that can get hit by traffic.

Comment: Well in that case performance shouldn't be an issue. Actually, one of the django core devs once told me that as a rule of thumb, that if something takes more than 10-15 lines and there is a way to abstract it, you should. Maybe that's a bit extreme in some cases but I always keep that in mind now.

Comment: I like the ideas on scaling —as the business grows there will be other PDFs to create so a separate app does make sense. Also,queing the generation and emails would be a good idea, then they could be run by a cron job and have minimal impact on the web server - nice thought, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can in principle do it in an app (the concept of reusable apps is the basis for their existence)

However not many people do it/not many applications require it. It depends on how/if the functionality will be shared. In other words there must be a real benefit.

The code normally goes in both the view/s and in the models (to isolate code and for the model managers)

Comment: Thanks, so maybe an alternative is as suggested above - to extract the code into a separate create_pdf.py file, which I assume that I would need to import into the main view file?

Comment: And would that separate file be considered a sub view or something?

Comment: Just a module containing functions to be called by the view